# View error "str is not callable" with ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to add Select field to form for field with type ForeignKey and use for this ModelChoiceField. But this form doesn`t rendering and throw error

> "'str' object is not callable"
>   on the line " {{ **form_ord.all_users**}}
>   {{ form_ord.pay_method }} {{ form_ord.pay }}" in order_add.html file.

What can I use to create form for model with ForeignKey field?

**order.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    PAY_METHOD_CHOISES = (
        ('CASH', 'cash'),
        ('CREDIT', 'credit card'),
        ('CHECK', 'check'),
    )
    pay_method = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAY_METHOD_CHOISES,
                                  default='cash')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(UsersData)
    pay = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id.user_name

    def pay_or_not(self):
        if self.pay:
            result = 'paid'
        else:
            result = 'not paid'
        return result

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    all_users = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UsersData.objects.all(),
                                       empty_label=None, initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['user_id', 'pay_method', 'pay', 'all_users']
```

**view_order.py**

```
def order_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_order = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form_order.is_valid():
            part_order_form = form_order.save(commit=False)
            value_user = form_order.cleaned_data.get('all_users')
            user = UsersData.objects.get(use_name=value_user)
            part_order_form.user_id = user
            part_order_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/sushi_rinjin/orders/')
    else:
        form_order = OrderForm()
        return render(request, 'sushi_rinjin/forms/order_add.html',
                      {'form_ord': form_order})
```

**order_add.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'sushi_rinjin:add_order'  %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_ord.all_users}} {{ form_ord.pay_method }} {{ form_ord.pay }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add Order" />
</form>
```

Traceback:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/sushi_rinjin/order_add/
>
> Django Version: 1.11.6 Python Version: 3.5.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['sushi_rinjin.apps.SushiRinjinConfig',  'django.contrib.admin', 
>   'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template error: In template
>   /home/anastasiia/Документы/Python-Programs.git/Py_Project/sushi/sushi_rinjin/templates/sushi_rinjin/forms/order_add.html,
>   error at line 3    'str' object is not callable   1 :     2 :     {%
>   csrf_token %}    3 :      {{ form_ord.all_users}}  {{
>   form_ord.pay_method }} {{ form_ord.pay }}    4 :         5 :
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/anastasiia/Документы/Python-Programs.git/Py_Project/sushi/sushi_rinjin/views/view_order.py"
>   in order_add
>     46.                       {'form_ord': form_order})
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in
>   render
>     30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in
>   render_to_string
>     68.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     66.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     207.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     1046.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_value_in_context
>     1024.     value = force_text(value)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py"
>   in force_text
>     76.                     s = six.text_type(s)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py" in
>   
>     385.         klass.**str** = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in
>   **str**
>     41.         return self.as_widget()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in
>   as_widget
>     101.         attrs = self.build_widget_attrs(attrs, widget)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in
>   build_widget_attrs
>     257.         if widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial) and self.field.required and self.form.use_required_attribute:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py"
>   in use_required_attribute
>     689.         first_choice = next(iter(self.choices), None)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in **iter**
>     1140.             yield self.choice(obj)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in choice
>     1146.         return (self.field.prepare_value(obj), self.field.label_from_instance(obj))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in label_from_instance
>     1211.         return force_text(obj)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py"
>   in force_text
>     76.                     s = six.text_type(s)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /sushi_rinjin/order_add/ Exception Value:
>   'str' object is not callable

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view_index.index, name='index'),
    url(r'menu/', view_menu.index, name='menu'),
    url(r'ingredients/', view_ingred.index, name='ingredients'),
    url(r'orders/', view_order.index, name='orders'),
    url(r'^order/(?P<id_order>[0-9]+)/$', view_order.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'ingredient_add/', view_ingred.ingred_add, name='add_ingred'),
    url(r'dish_add/', view_menu.dish_add, name='add_dish'),
    url(r'order_add/', view_order.order_add, name='add_order'),
]
```

Comment: can we see your url.py ?

Comment: Added urls.py

Note: If I delete "{{ form_ord.all_users}}" from order_add.html everything works.

Comment: did you try simple `{{ form_ord }}` and why you add `all_users` if you have the field `user_id` ?

Comment: Can you print UsersData.objects.all() ? It seems you had been create users and they can't be parse by the form in runtime. If I were you then I would  clear DB and try again.

Comment: And try to set `initial=None` or remove this param.

Comment: @BearBrown I try to use a simle variant {{ form_ord }} with user_id, but an error is the same

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander I send to form  'users': UsersData.objects.all() and then print as a list, all is OK:   <ul>
        {%  for obj in users %}
            <li> {{ obj.user_name }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander But when I send   {'form_ord': form_order}, where form_order = OrderForm(), it doesn`t work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `@property` decorator from `__str__` method.

Comment: Could you put the complete error message_? with the stack trace

Comment: Added traceback.

Comment: Perhaps but you definitely shouldn't be making `__str__`  a property.

Comment: I deleted @property in another model (UserData) and all become all right, thanks!